# How to call and pass the value to function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to call the remove function that is in my ShoppingCartScreen component in my CartList component. I also want to pass in values from the CartList component class. I kept getting issues when I tried to call the add in my CartList class.

```
export default class ShoppingCartScreen extends Component {
        remove = (qty) => {
            let q = qty
            if (q > 1) {
                q = q - 1;
                this.setState({ qty: q })
            }
    
    
        }
    
    render() {
      return (
              <View>
                <ScrollView backgroundColor='#bbb'>
                   <CartList
                     remove = {this.remove}  />
                    </ScrollView>           
              </View>
                    )
              }
   



export default class CartList extends Component {
 render() {
      
      return (
          <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.add(this.state.qty)}>
                  <Icon
                       name="md-close"
                       size={25}
                       color='black'
                       style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }}
                       iconStyle={{ marginRight: 0 }}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
       )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you pass `remove` to the `CartList` and then inside call `this.props.add`, so you need to change the name. Second, you need to upgrade `this.props.remove` call to an arrow function:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.remove(this.state.qty)}>
```

`onPress` expects that you pass a function to be called. When the component is rendered, the `this.props.add(this.state.qty)` gets evaluated immediately because it is already a function call. This is why you must use an arrow function is this case.